# Is the length of audio file in .WAV format (second) related to file size?

Tags: audio, wav, javasound

I wrote a java code to read .wav file into a byte array.

.WAV file are 44100Hz (sample per second), 16 bits depth

For audio with length 1 min, I expect to get a byte array with length 60*44100*2. (1 min = 60 sec, each second has 44100 samples, each sample contains 16bits = 2bytes)

However, the array length seems to be doubled. Is there any explanation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is a normal recording it will be Stereo - 2 channels. So you get all this data for each channel.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer !! The .WAV file has channel as stereo. So got right and left channel.